# ChangeNotifier shows error when navigate to next page

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, provider

I'm new to flutter and building an app using ChangeNotifier and provider for an MVVM design pattern. When a login page loads I want to check it's already logged in or not. if it's already logged in,  then navigate to the next page. But it show's  following error. [image]

My ChangeNotifier Binding code from splash screen

```
   _moveToNextScreen() async {
    await Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (_) => LoginViewModel(),
                  child: LoginScreen(),
                ),
        ));
  }
```

Login Screen code

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;

  //controller for login
  TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Size size; // calculate screen size

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loginViewModel = Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    _loginViewModel.loggedInOrNot();
    checkLoginStatus();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkLoginStatus() async {
    print('vcal - ${_loginViewModel.getIsLoggedIn}');
    if (_loginViewModel.getIsLoggedIn == true) {
      //_moveToNextScreen();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     _loginViewModel = Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context);
    size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: green,
      //IP screen
      // Asset Tracker- Text
      body: _loginScreen(),
    );
  }
```

my LoginViewModel.dart

```
class LoginViewModel extends ChangeNotifier{

  LoginRepository _loginRepository = LoginRepository();

  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;
  

  void loggedInOrNot() async {
    _isLoggedIn =  !_isLoggedIn;
    //await _loginRepository.checkToken();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get getIsLoggedIn => _isLoggedIn;
  bool get getIsLoading => _isLoading;

}
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you have to use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` or `ProxyProvider` there but I would suggest use condition there like `_loginViewModel.getIsLoggedIn?page1:page2`

Comment: if i call _loginViewModel.getIsLoggedIn it return false. it doesn't check for loggedInorNot. how can i assign value of _isLoadedIn to await _loginRepository.checkToken() which return bool value.

Comment: you should use provider in your login repo I think I found this code which might be helpful https://github.com/itsatifsiddiqui/providerLogin/blob/master/lib/model/user_repository.dart

Answer (score 1):

You should access a provider like this

```
Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context, listen: false).getIsLoggedIn;
```

and Wrap with Consumer widget with top of the ui class widget tree

Consumer is rebuilds your UI every state changes.

For more info about provider & consumer I recommend you to their documentation find it [**from here**](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/)

Comment: can I get the documentation link?

Comment: Provider.of<LoginViewModel>(context, listen: false).getIsLoggedIn this value is always false. how to assign it's value to await _loginRepository.checkToken() which return bool value. I wan't to call lloggedInOrNot() for updating isLoggedIn value.

Comment: Check user login? U set its value to true or false then notifyListners method notifies all listeners in your app. Your ui you first check isLoading is true then show loading screen if false you can check user logs in or not !!

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe because when you go to the next page you create **new** `ChangeNotifierProvider`. You have to place it above these two Widgets, e.g. above the `MaterialApp`/`CupertinoApp`

Comment: I have 3 ViewModels with change notifier. How can I add ViewModel for different views?

Comment: For example you have Widget1, Widget2, Widget3, Widget4. Widget2 and Widget3 are inheritors of Widget1 and Widget4 is inheritor of Widget3. If you place your `Provider` above the Widget1 you also can use it in the Widget2, Widget3 and Widget 4. Write me if it wasn't your question

Comment: If I place change notifier with multi provider, then I am able to use my LoginViewModel in any screen. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, in any widget under your multi provider